# Why is P or not P is unsatisifiable by construction?

Tags: proof-writing, constructive-mathematics

A proof of predicate logic inability to express graph reachibility ([page 63](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~plragde/cs245/07-predsem.pdf)) involves a formula which can be interpreted as *(there is no path, no matter what is the length) or (there is some path)*. The proof says that it is "unsatifiable by construction," [which means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_construction) means that some example is provided. Which example are they talking about?

> Let $\Delta = \{ \neq \phi_n \mid n \geq 0 \} \cup \{ \phi [c/u][c'/v] \}$.
>   By construction, $\Delta$ is unsatisfiable, because the first set says, "There is no path of any finite length from $c$ to $c'$, and the second set says that there is one.

I would say that $\Delta$ is not just satisfiable but it is valid (I hardly can come up with an example where it is not the case). Anyway, my question is what is this example has to do with the prove by construction? The proof by constraction assumes that you build an example of what to be (dis)proved. Which lemma is proved by (construction of) $\Delta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, 'unsatisfiable by construction' means that the formula itself has been constructed such that there is no way to satisfy it. A model that satisfies it would have some finite path from $c$ to $c'$ by $\phi[c/u][c'/v]$. That path has a length that is some natural number $n$. But by $\{ \neg \phi_n | n \geq 0 \}$, for all $n$ there is no path from $c$ to $c'$ of length $n$.

For your second question, I'm not sure where it says that $\{ \neg \phi_n | n \geq 0\}$ is a finite set; clearly it isn't, since it has one element for each nonnegative integer.

Comment: I do not see how does your contradiction invalidate the $\Delta$. Either there is no way or there is one. It is universally true, valid, statement. How can you say its unsatisifiable? Actually, I wanted to know what what this case has to do with the proof `by construction`. The prove `by construction` says that you must construct an example of what you are going to prove. Here, they define a set and say that it is not satisfable. What is proven by consctruction?

Comment: You're reading an 'or' in the formula where you should be reading an 'and'. In order for a set such as $\Delta$ to be satisfied by a model, *every formula* in the set has to be satisfied simultaneously by that model. For any model $G$, if $G$ satisfies $\phi[c/u][c'/v]$, then there is some $n$ such that $G$ does not satisfy $\neg \phi_n$. Therefore, it cannot satisfy $\Delta$, since $\neg \phi_n \in \Delta$.

Comment: As for "by construction": the phrase has two related meanings. A "proof by construction" is a proof that asserts an object exists by constructing it. The sentence "By construction, X has property Y" means "the way in which X was described (i.e., its construction) makes it easy to see that it has property Y".